# Api Platform - NotFoundHttpException when calling an itemOperations endpoint

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have created a custom endpoint using API Platform:

```
#[ApiResource(
collectionOperations: [
    'get' => [
        'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['product:list']]
    ],
    'post' => [
        'denormalization_context' => ['groups' => ['product:list']]
    ]
],
itemOperations: [
    'get_by_user' => [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'path' => '/products/user/{id}',
        'read' => 'false',
        'controller' => ProductController::class,
        'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['product:list']],
        'openapi_context' => [
            'summary'     => 'Retrieves the Product collection for a specific user ID',
            'description' => 'Retrieves the Product collection for a specific user ID'
        ]
    ],
], )]
```

and the controller method:

```
public function __invoke(int $id): array
{
    $prod = $this->productRepository
        ->findBy(
            ['user' => $id],
        );

    return $prod;
}
```

And the error when I try to call this endpoint is:

`Not Found - api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/EventListener/ReadListener.php`

Has anyone any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: Do you have any product records for that user?  What happens if you don't use a `normalization_context`?

Comment: Yes I do have products records for that user and I still have the 'not-found' issue if I don't use the normalization_context..